# Remove first and last grid lines in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to separate the points on a line graph by vertical lines in Highcharts. I can do this with grid lines, but I would like the lines to display only between points and not before the first point and after the last one. In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfrxL31s/) there should be no grid lines before 'Jan' and after 'Dec'. Is it possible?

Here is my x-axis

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        gridLineWidth: 1, 
        minorGridLineWidth: 0  
      }
```

Comment: Highcharts lib doesn't have option like `showLastGrid`. You can create your idea on [userVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general). Or just overlay first and last grid-line with [plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines).

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus! Hadn't thought of using plotLines in that way, but it works!

Comment: The css route.  http://jsfiddle.net/8ca2rvd7/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just delete two last `<path>` elements in the group `<g>` element .
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xfrxL31s/1/) `on fiddle`

Comment: This sure is a workable solution for JS. How about a C# program (WinForms) using DevExpress xrChart? Anyone..?

Comment: I've been able to do this as well via css. http://jsfiddle.net/8ca2rvd7/3/

Answer (score -1):

Axis has classname attribute.

1. set an axis classname.
2. set CSS to hide the last path element.

```css
.axis-container { 
    path:last-child {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately mine are sometimes rendering out of order.  So the second one down ends up getting hidden.